# Similarity of vertices in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-group

We say that two vertices $u,v \in V$ in a graph  $G=(V,E)$ are *similar* if there is a graph automorphism $\sigma \in Aut(G)$, s.t. $\sigma(u)=v$.

Is there a graph $G$ with $u,v \in V$ not similar, so that $G-u$ is isomorphic to $G-v$? Here, $G-a$ is the resulting graph after throwing out the vertex $a\in V$ and all the edges $e \in E$ with $a \in e$.

According to the exercise there should be one, but right now I feel closer to disproving it than to prove it. If there is one, could you give me a hint (maybe on the number of vertices, or so)

Comment: There’s a counterexample on eight vertices.

Comment: Is the middle paragraph of your question your own intellectual property, or did you copy it from some book? If it is copied, please acknowledge the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminology I have heard is u and v are in the same "orbit" under the automorphism.

Anyway, there is an example in this paper:

"Automorphism groups of a graphand a vertex-deleted subgraph" Hartkee et al **The Electronic Journal Of Combinatorics** V7 (2010)

but it's a little large, so I searched through all the simple graphs on eight vertices, and found this smallest one:

[image]

It looks like there are 17 other examples in the eights.